# How to make a link open in a Chrome browser from a Outlook add-in (Office 365)?

Tags: google-chrome, office365, outlook-addin

I have seen a href with 'microsoft-edge' in it which opens the url in Edge. I was wondering if there was anything similar for Chrome. I have developed an add-in for Outlook and all the href opens in Internet Explorer. I have also seen few other add-ins that open the link in chrome browser and not in ie, which is exactly what I want but not sure how this can be achieved

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Force Outlook Add-in popup to open with embedded browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45470794/force-outlook-add-in-popup-to-open-with-embedded-browser)

Comment: There it says to use displayDialogAsync API but that just opens a window and not chrome specifically